# Unable to set a input value on Google Forms using Javascript

Tags: javascript, input, google-chrome-extension, textarea, google-forms

I'm trying to make a autofill extension for google forms but i can't change the input/textarea value. this is the code on content.js `document.getElementsByClassName('quantumWizTextinputPapertextareaInput exportTextarea')[0].value = "Some Answer"`[This is what happens on google forms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g74zR.png)

if i try to submit it i get an error saying the question is obligatory
[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDuvI.png)

if i type or delete something on the input then it recognizes the text and i can submit it. I really wish someone could help me [Here is the form link](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSej4-Ylrlf412Coxp6jm4TrPcUuRZRoMbzb8l4NWu_iXCSh1g/viewform)

Comment: You need to set value for `data-initial-value` attribute as well.

Comment: Still doesn’t work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround for this using `execCommand`. Since google forms use dynamic js execution using jscontroller and jsaction, just setting value will not work well.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("quantumWizTextinputPapertextareaInput exportTextarea")[0].focus();
document.execCommand('insertText', false, 'Some Answer');
```